# Problem: grub set to use new kernel, but still boots into old kernel

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kernel

I built a new kernel (4.4.0-64, on Ubuntu 16.04).

Now I want to always boot from the `4.4.0-64` kernel, but, no matter what I set in `/etc/default/grub`'s `GRUB_DEFAULT` to - the OS will always boot with the old kernel.

The below demonstrates that even though I set the `GRUB_DEFAULT` to be the `4.4.0-64` kernel, the OS still boots into the old `4.4.0-040400` kernel:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig | grep menuentry | grep generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-040400-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-040400-generic-init-upstart-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-040400-generic-recovery-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-init-upstart-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-recovery-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {

$ grep GRUB_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e>gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e"

$ sudo update-grub && sudo reboot

<reboot>

$ uname -r
4.4.0-040400-generic


$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7

$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

$ grep GRUB_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e"




$ sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

<reboot>

$ uname -r
4.4.0-040400-generic

$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep -i "set default"
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set default="gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e"
```

**Can you suggest what can I do in order to boot into the new 4.4.0-64 kernel?**

***Edit 1:***

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig
Generating grub configuration file ...
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="${saved_entry}"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
                set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
        else
                set vt_handoff=
        fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        recordfail
        savedefault
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-040400-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
                recordfail
        savedefault
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-040400-generic-init-upstart-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
                recordfail
        savedefault
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-040400-generic-recovery-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-040400-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro recovery nomodeset
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
        }
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
                recordfail
        savedefault
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-64-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-init-upstart-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
                recordfail
        savedefault
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-64-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-recovery-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-64-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e ro recovery nomodeset
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
        }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
        fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
done
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in this, but I have found similar info that I think you might use to solve your problem.

1) run in terminal: `grep submenu /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

2) find your kernels in the list and pay attention to their ordering.  The ordering starts at "0".  So the first kernel in the list is "0", the second one is "1" etc.

3) then run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, and got to line: `GRUB_DEFAULT=`
and using info from step 2, enter `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` (for kernel 0 in list), or `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` (for kernel 1 in list) etc (or whatever the order number of the kernel you want is, according to the output of `grep submenu /boot/grub/grub.cfg`).

4) `sudo update-grub`

5) reboot.

Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GWD72. These are plain vanilla instructions to set a new default kernel. I tried these (as indicated in my question). They didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to remove the kernel that is overlapping the last kernel update.

To list available kernels:

```
dpkg-query -l | awk '/linux-image-*/ {print $2}'
```

To remove a kernel:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-[replace reference]
```

In the specific case:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic
```

After update the grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GRUB_DEFAULT looks strange to me.  When I want to boot into an old kernel, I use a GRUB_DEFAULT like this

`GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic"`

Comment: Isn't your comparable to mine (in the OP): `GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e>gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e"
`? Based on my `menuentry` list, what do you suggest I should use?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the menuentry commands you use, but my example lists the full text of the desired GRUB menu entry, including both the top level (before the >) and second level lines. If "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic" appears on the GRUB menu screen, it needs to be included in the GRUB_DEFAULT entry. '

Comment: Maybe GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic>gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013-568e-483b-befe-6a84f0ce102e" if that is how the 2 levels of your menu look? Again, I am not familiar with menuentry.

Comment: See `Edit 1` for how menuentries look like.

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, you have 3 levels of menu?  Never seen that, but perhaps it should be:GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-64-generic>gnulinux-4.4.0-64-generic-advanced-6fefb013‌​-568e-483b-befe-6a84‌​f0ce102e"